# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext after adding JpaSpecificationExecutor<Customer>

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I can not run JUnit tests after adding JpaSpecificationExecutor, exactly method in CustomerRepository causing that

List findAll(CustomerSpecification customerSpecification);

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = AbcTests.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
class AbcTests {

    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    @Test
    void contextLoads(){

    }
```

}

This is how the stactrace looks like

```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> 
>   at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
>   at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
>   at
> org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
>   at
> org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
>   at
> org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
>   at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
>   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
>   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
>   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
>   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
>   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
>   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
>   at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)    at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
>   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
>   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
>   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
>   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
>   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
>   at
> com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
>   at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
>   at
> com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
>   at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
>   at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
>   at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'addressRepository' defined in
> com.pawelzielinski.repository.AddressRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> ElectricityProviderApplicationTests: Cannot create inner bean '(inner
> bean)#47c64cfe' of type
> [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
> bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name '(inner bean)#47c64cfe': Cannot resolve
> reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
> argument; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:934)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
>   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
>   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
>   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   at
> org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:144)
>   at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>   at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>   ... 71 more Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name '(inner bean)#47c64cfe': Cannot resolve
> reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
> argument; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:510)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
>   ... 89 more Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:872)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
>   ... 97 more
```

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository {

    Customer save(Customer customer);
    List<Customer> findAll();
    Customer getById(Integer id);
    void deleteById(Integer id);
    List<Customer> findAll(CustomerSpecification customerSpecification);
}


@Repository
interface SqlCustomerRepository extends CustomerRepository, JpaRepository<Customer, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Customer> {

}
```

above is SqlCustomerRepository and CustomerRepository. I want to make filtering by using specifiactions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.lwiejek</groupId>
    <artifactId>electricity-provider</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>taskex</name>
    <description>task/description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace for the error?

Comment: @TomazFernandes stacktrace added

Comment: Could you add the entire repository class as well?

Comment: @tbjorch already did it

Comment: Please add your pom.xml (if you are using Maven)

Comment: It's weird how you organized the class hierarchy. CustomerRepository isn't necessary and furthermore it can cause issues like multiple inheritance (diamond problem).

Answer (score 1):

This three annotations in Test class helped me to resolve problem:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.lwiejek*")
@ComponentScan({"com.lwiejek*"})
```